# Query a List of Data in a Column from another sheet Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a list of data in a column that keeps changing in size.

At the moment I am using the script below which is working for only 1 cell. My range would be O2:O

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('PrepSheet'), true);
spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=QUERY({\'LOCATIONS\'!$A$2:$C},"SELECT * WHERE Col1 = \'" & 
O2 & "\' ")');

How could I add a range like this to the query   \'" & O2:O & "\' ")'); ??
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build out a single regular expression from `O2:O` to match `Col1` against.

```
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=QUERY({\'LOCATIONS\'!$A$2:$C},"SELECT * WHERE Col1 MATCHES \'" & JOIN("|",FILTER(O2:O, NOT(ISBLANK(O2:O)))) & "\' ")');
```

I'd also simplify your code a bit.

```
function insertQuery() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('PrepSheet');
  sheet.getRange('A2').activate().setFormula('=QUERY({\'LOCATIONS\'!$A$2:$C},"SELECT * WHERE Col1 MATCHES \'" & JOIN("|",FILTER(O2:O, NOT(ISBLANK(O2:O)))) & "\' ")');
}
```

Comment: Hi Diego When I ran the code on A2, of sheet displaying Query result - it only gave me 1 result where I was expecting more. There are 18 cells with data in Column 0  that query needed to give back results for. I double checked your additions to make sure i copied it correctly as well.

Comment: See link to example sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QPEEZBxDlQoxdwzo9uHqXOTp8JphgoxxzOKCcxqLe7I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @TomSawkins Sorry I misinterpreted your question. I've modified my answer. Please see if it works for you.

Comment: Hi Diego - Would like to limit the results the query returns to 3 Maximum. Could you help please. Thank you